# find the plain text and key by cipher with vigenere alogorithm

Tags: python

this is my python code and I want to decrypt a ciphertext without knowing key and at the end find the plain text and key. for example for ciphertext "Vyc fnqkm spdpv nqo hjfxa qmcg 13 eiha umvl" it should return the plain text "The quick brown fox jumps over 13 lazy dogs" and key "cryptii" . But it does not return what I want . How can I edit it?

Here is my code :

```
import re
import collections

def vigenere_decrypt(ciphertext, key):
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
plaintext = ''
for i, char in enumerate(ciphertext):
    if char.isalpha():
        key_char = key[i % len(key)].upper()
        key_idx = alphabet.index(key_char)
        if char.islower():
            char = char.upper()
        char_idx = alphabet.index(char)
        decrypted_idx = (char_idx - key_idx) % 26
        plaintext += alphabet[decrypted_idx]
    else:
        plaintext += char
  return plaintext

def kasiski_examination(ciphertext):
  repeating_sequences = {}
  for length in range(3, 6):
    for i in range(len(ciphertext) - length + 1):
        sequence = ciphertext[i:i+length]
        if sequence in repeating_sequences:
            repeating_sequences[sequence].append(i)
        else:
            repeating_sequences[sequence] = [i]

  distances = {}
  for sequence, indices in repeating_sequences.items():
    if len(indices) > 1:
        for i in range(len(indices) - 1):
            distance = indices[i + 1] - indices[i]
            if distance > 0:
                if sequence in distances:
                    distances[sequence].append(distance)
                else:
                    distances[sequence] = [distance]

  return distances

def guess_key_length(distances):
    common_distances = collections.Counter()
    for distances_list in distances.values():
        for distance in distances_list:
            common_distances[distance] += 1

    if common_distances:
        key_length_guess = common_distances.most_common(1)[0][0]
    else:
        key_length_guess = 3  # A default value in case no common distances are found
    return key_length_guess

def frequency_analysis(grouped_text):
    most_common_letter = collections.Counter(grouped_text).most_common(1)[0][0]
     key_char = chr(((ord(most_common_letter) - ord('E')) % 26) + ord('A'))
    return key_char

 def vigenere_break(ciphertext):
    distances = kasiski_examination(ciphertext)
    key_length = guess_key_length(distances)

    key = ''
    for i in range(key_length):
        group = [ciphertext[j] for j in range(i, len(ciphertext), key_length)]
         key_char = frequency_analysis(group)
         key += key_char

     plaintext = vigenere_decrypt(ciphertext, key)
     return key, plaintext

 ciphertext = "Vyc fnqkm spdpv nqo hjfxa qmcg 13 eiha umvl."
 key, plaintext = vigenere_break(ciphertext)
 print("Ciphertext:", ciphertext)
 print("Decrypted Plaintext:", plaintext)
 print("Key:", key)
```

Comment: please fix the code formatting

Comment: If `for length in range(3,6):` is supposed to iterate over possible key lengths then it is too short for `"cryptii"` (or is that supposed to be `"crypti"`? - still too short). `range(3,6)` ends with `length = 5`.